# Java on read from csv and display on jTable

Tags: java, swing, csv

I'm having stuck at reading back from csv wheres i'm success at creating the csv.
the problem I'm facing is I cant get a clue on how to obtain the values getting from csv back to the jTable.
I'm not having any other problems aside from `public void fromCsv`

```
  class FCMS extends JFrame{
    String header[] = {"Firstname","Lastname","FCMS ID","Email"};
    String data[][];
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JPanel pane_input = new JPanel();
    JLabel lbl_firstname = new JLabel(" Firstname");
    JLabel lbl_lastname = new JLabel(" Lastname");
        JLabel lbl_id = new JLabel(" FCMS ID");
    JLabel lbl_email = new JLabel(" Email");
    JTextField txt_firstname = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField txt_lastname = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField txt_id = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField txt_email = new JTextField(10);
    JButton btn_add = new JButton("Add Entry");
    JButton btn_Csv = new JButton("Export to Csv");
        JButton btn_load = new JButton("Load From Csv");

    public FCMS(){
        setSize(200,200);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Flight Crew Management System");

        btn_add.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        btn_Csv.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
                btn_load.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_L);

        pane_input.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        pane_input.add(lbl_firstname);
        pane_input.add(txt_firstname);
        pane_input.add(lbl_lastname);
        pane_input.add(txt_lastname);
                pane_input.add(lbl_id);
                pane_input.add(txt_id);
        pane_input.add(lbl_email);
        pane_input.add(txt_email);
                pane_input.add(btn_add);
        pane_input.add(btn_Csv);        
                pane_input.add(btn_load);

        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(pane_input, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(pane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        btn_add.addActionListener(new AksyonListener());
        btn_Csv.addActionListener(new AksyonListener());
                btn_load.addActionListener(new AksyonListener());
        txt_email.addActionListener(new AksyonListener());
    }

    public void toCsv(JTable table, File file){
        try{
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                FileWriter Csv = new FileWriter(file);


                for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++){
                        Csv.write(model.getColumnName(i) + ",");
                }

                Csv.write("\n");

                for(int i=0; i< model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        for(int j=0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                                Csv.write(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+",");
                        }
                        Csv.write("\n");
                }

                Csv.close();
        }catch(IOException e){ System.out.println(e); }
    }

    public void fromCsv(File file){

        BufferedReader fileReader = null;
        model.setRowCount(0);

        try{

                 //Create the file reader
                fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                //Read the CSV file header to skip it
                fileReader.readLine();

                int fn = 0;
                int ln = 1;
                 int id = 2;
                int email = 3;


                String line="";
                 //Read the file line by line starting from the second line
                while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //Get all tokens available in line
                    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                    model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{Long.parseLong(tokens[fn]), tokens[ln], tokens[id], tokens[email]});
                 //   if (tokens.length > 0) {

                 //   }
                }


                 /*  for(int i=0; i< tokens.length; i++) {
                            for(int j=0; j < tokens.length; j++) {
                                //Csv.read(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
                                model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{Long.parseLong(tokens[fn]), tokens[ln], tokens[id], tokens[email]});
                            }
                           // Csv.read("\n");
                    }*/

                fileReader.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileReader !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new FCMS();
    }

    class AksyonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == btn_add || e.getSource() == txt_email){
                    String fn = txt_firstname.getText();
                    String ln = txt_lastname.getText();
                    String id = txt_id.getText();
                    String mail = txt_email.getText();

                    txt_firstname.setText("");
                    txt_lastname.setText("");
                    txt_id.setText("");
                    txt_email.setText("");
                    txt_firstname.requestFocus();

                    model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{fn, ln, id, mail});
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == btn_Csv){

                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                int option = fc.showSaveDialog(FCMS.this);

                if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getName(); 
                    String path = fc.getSelectedFile().getParentFile().getPath();

                    int len = filename.length();
                    String ext = "";
                    String file = "";

                        if(len > 4){
                                ext = filename.substring(len-4, len);
                        }

                        if(ext.equals(".csv")){
                                file = path + "\\" + filename; 
                        }else{
                                file = path + "\\" + filename + ".csv"; 
                        }
                    toCsv(table, new File(file));
                }
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == btn_load){

                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                int option = fc.showOpenDialog(FCMS.this);

                if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getName(); 
                        String path = fc.getSelectedFile().getParentFile().getPath();

                        int len = filename.length();
                        String ext = "";
                        String file = "";

                            if(len > 4){
                                    ext = filename.substring(len-4, len);
                            }

                            if(ext.equals(".csv")){
                                    file = path + "\\" + filename; 
                            }else{
                                    file = path + "\\" + filename + ".csv"; 
                            }

                        fromCsv(new File(file));

                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is solved:

```
try{

                 //Create the file reader
                fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                //Read the CSV file header to skip it
                fileReader.readLine();

                int fn = 0;
                int ln = 1;
                int id = 2;
                int email = 3;


                String line="";
                 //Read the file line by line starting from the second line
                while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //Get all tokens available in line
                    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                    model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{(tokens[fn]), tokens[ln], tokens[id], tokens[email]});
                 //   if (tokens.length > 0) {

                 //   }
                }


                 /*  for(int i=0; i< tokens.length; i++) {
                            for(int j=0; j < tokens.length; j++) {
                                //Csv.read(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
                                model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{Long.parseLong(tokens[fn]), tokens[ln], tokens[id], tokens[email]});
                            }
                           // Csv.read("\n");
                    }*/

                fileReader.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
```

Above is where you split one line of data into an array, so above is where you then need to take the data from the array and add it to the TableModel.

So your code should be:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{Long.parseLong(tokens[fn]), tokens[ln], tokens[id], tokens[email]});
```

Then there is no need for the second loop.

However, the above code will just append data to the existing "model", so you may also need to clear all the data in the model. You can do this by adding:

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

before the loop.

Comment: so that means i should just do in a while loop without using previous for loop and if(tokens.length >0) ?

Comment: nvm, I follow your advice and I solved it, and removed Long.parseLong due to number format exception and it is good to go.